# Calculating uncertainty (entropy) from density distribution in R

Tags: r, entropy

I wonder what would be the best and most correct way to estimate an Entropy from a probability density function in R? I have some real-values that are not probabilities, and I would like to get some measure of "uneaveness" of those values. Thus, I was thinking about entropy. Would something like this work:

```
entropy(density(dat$X), unit='log2'),
```

assuming that I am using *entropy* function from the **entropy** package.

Are there some other ways of estimating uncertainty from real-valued vector?

Many thanks! PM

Comment: If you are looking for statistical methods to estimate entropy, you should probably post your question to [stats.se]. Right now this doesn't sound like a specific programming question that would be appropriate for Stack Overflow.